# Submenu does not stay open

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a little problem here with my dropdown menu.
When I hover a link, the submenu slides out but doesn't stay open.

The problem has something to do with my "content" div element, because when I remove this div it works. But I can't find my error.

Maybe someone can have a look at it. ;-)

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/B4aDM/1/) is the menu.

Comment: It would help if you would add the code you were having problems with directly to this SO page.  I think that will help others visiting this thread with a similar issue, assuming your JS Fiddle code page has changed already or will eventually disappear (which I think is a fair assumption).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the fact the #content comes after #navigation and it's z-index is higher. If you set both position: relative and set the z-index of #navigation to a higher value than #content it'll work as you expect. See http://jsfiddle.net/tangibleJ/B4aDM/2/.